# R: combine rows with common information

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
V1 V2  V3    V4    V5  V6  V7 V8            V9
1  .  mRNA  1300  9000  .  +  .  ID=mRNA00003;Parent=gene00001;Name=EDEN.3
1  .  exon  1300  1500  .  +  .  ID=exon00001;Parent=mRNA00001
1  .  exon  1300  1500  .  +  .  ID=exon00001;Parent=mRNA00002
1  .  exon  1300  1500  .  +  .  ID=exon00001;Parent=mRNA00003
```

Since the last 3 rows share mostly the same information (i.e. the first 8 columns are identical), I want to make them like this:

```
V1 V2  V3    V4    V5  V6  V7 V8            V9
1  .  mRNA  1300  9000  .  +  .  ID=mRNA00003;Parent=gene00001;Name=EDEN.3
1  .  exon  1300  1500  .  +  .  ID=exon00001;Parent=mRNA00001;mRNA00002;mRNA00003
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Try `aggregate(V9 ~ ., df, toString)`

Comment: @ANG or `function(x) { paste(x, sep=';') }`

Comment: @n.caillou thanks for the ingenious idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like?

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8) %>%
  summarise(V9 = paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(paste(V9, collapse = ';'), split = ";"))),collapse=";"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments, you can also try `aggregate(V9 ~ ., df, function(x){paste(x, sep = ";")})`

Comment: Thanks so much! This one works beautifully, too! Could you be very kind explain how it works? I am not sure about the "V9 ~ ." part.

Comment: This means that we are creating groups of unique `V9` based on a combination of all the other columns i.e. from `V1` to `V8`. We can also write `V9 ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 + V6 + V7 + V8`