# combine rows with similar column values but not identical column values

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I am messing with a data set of my finances over the past 10 weeks.. I am trying to sum the amounts spent/deposited by each store description.. I was able to get that done with.

```
 totalofeachstore <- FullStatement %>% group_by( Description) %>% 
 summarise_at(vars(Amount), funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

or

```
 totalofeachstore <- totalofeachstore %>%
 group_by(Description) %>%
 summarize(Amount = sum(Amount))
```

the problem I am finding is that many stores include their store # or description on my statements.. An example would be.

```
 Arco Gas #345   -$45.54
 Arco Gas #678   -$52.72
```

Because of the store #'s the sums don't collapse like I expected.  Is there any way to collapse/sum rows with similar names that are not identical?  For example in the following store names.. could I collapse all of the Amazon stores based on the keyword AMAZON or better yet, because of the odd AMZN and AMZ that are 4th and 5th down the list.. could I combine those off those key letters?

```
 AMAZON.COM*MT2M03AW1 AM PURCHASE AMZN.COM/BILL WA -8.08
 AMAZON.COM*MT80Z2EC0 AM PURCHASE AMZN.COM/BILL WA -13.28
 AMAZON.COM*MT8G19G51 AM PURCHASE AMZN.COM/BILL WA -31.03
 AMZ*Stride Rite PURCHASE Customerservi NY         -35.20
 AMZN MKTP US AMZN.COM/B PURCHASE AMZN.COM/BILL WA -181.08
 ARBYS 0154 PURCHASE                              -13.90
 ARCO #42472 AM PURCHASE                          -30.73
 ARCO #42493 AM PURCHASE                          -29.35
 AUNT CHILADA'S PURCHASE                          -15.98
```

I found similar questions about collapsing similar rows but they were not trying to sum at the same time.. those questions are as follows.

[R combine rows with similar values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50312514/r-combine-rows-with-similar-values)
[R: combine rows with common information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963219/r-combine-rows-with-common-information)

EDIT1
after some additional GOOGLE searching.. I found some "regex" suggestions that may be able to do what I am looking for.. However, I have zero idea how these work and doing a ?grep didn't help me much.. This looks to be quite a bit more complicated than I currently understand.. Can anyone help break this down for me?

from the ?grep in R.

```
 grep, grepl, regexpr, gregexpr and regexec search for matches to argument 
 pattern within each element of a character vector: they differ in the 
 format of and amount of detail in the results.

 sub and gsub perform replacement of the first and all matches respectively.

 grep(pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE,
 fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)

 grep("[a-z]", letters)

 txt <- c("arm","foot","lefroo", "bafoobar")
 if(length(i <- grep("foo", txt)))
 cat("'foo' appears at least once in\n\t", txt, "\n")
 i # 2 and 4
 txt[i]
```

EDIT2: 
Based on the suggestion below, this code was tried:

```
  Totals2 <- totalofeachstore %>%
  +   #remove everything after a *
  +   mutate(store_name = gsub("\\*.*","",Description),
  +          #remove everything after a space and a #
  +          store_name = gsub("\\ #.*","",store_name),
  +          #remove everything after a space and a number sequence
  +          store_name = gsub("\\ [0-9].*","",store_name),
  +          #assign the other Amazon purchases to Amazon
  +          store_name = 
         ifelse(str_detect(store_name,'AMZ')==TRUE,'AMAZON.COM',store_name))
```

but the following error keeps popping up.. I didn't think the gsub was part of a package other than base.. but this feels like I didn't load a package that contains "str_detect" or something..

```
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
 Evaluation error: could not find function "str_detect".
```

EDIT 3: Perfection!

Using the "tidyverse" package fixed the error I was receiving and everything works exactly as described which is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a fairly consistent pattern you can use? From the example you gave, it seems like # and * can be used to divide the business from the sub-categories.

So you could do something like this in dplyr:

```
df <- tibble(payment_amt = c(-8.08,-13.28,-31.03,-35.20,-181.08,-13.90,-30.73,-29.35,-15.98),
               description = c('AMAZON.COM*MT2M03AW1 AM PURCHASE AMZN.COM/BILL WA',
                           'AMAZON.COM*MT80Z2EC0 AM PURCHASE AMZN.COM/BILL WA',
                           'AMAZON.COM*MT8G19G51 AM PURCHASE AMZN.COM/BILL WA',
                           'AMZ*Stride Rite PURCHASE Customerservi NY',
                           'AMZN MKTP US AMZN.COM/B PURCHASE AMZN.COM/BILL WA',
                           'ARBYS 0154 PURCHASE',
                           'ARCO #42472 AM PURCHASE', 
                           'ARCO #42493 AM PURCHASE',
                           'AUNT CHILADAS PURCHASE'))

df <- df %>%
  #remove everything after a *
  mutate(store_name = gsub("\\*.*","",description),
  #remove everything after a space and a #
         store_name = gsub("\\ #.*","",store_name),
  #remove everything after a space and a number sequence
  store_name = gsub("\\ [0-9].*","",store_name),
  #assign the other Amazon purchases to Amazon
         store_name = ifelse(str_detect(store_name,'AMZ')==TRUE,'AMAZON.COM',store_name))

df_sums <- df %>%
  group_by(store_name) %>%
  summarize(payment_amt = sum(payment_amt)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(payment_amt)
```

Here are the results:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  store_name             payment_amt
  <chr>                        <dbl>
1 AMAZON.COM                  -269. 
2 ARCO                         -60.1
3 AUNT CHILADAS PURCHASE       -16.0
4 ARBYS          -13.9
```

Comment: Ill try this as soon as I can get a change... This looks EXACTLY like what I was hoping for!  I was just coming back to put another edit that I had been looking at the GSUB commands.. I should be able to test tonight at some point.   Thank you!

Comment: For the most part this is doing exactly as I wanted... however there is 1 issue that is popping up.."Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: could not find function "str_detect". not sure what this is referring to or how to fix it..
        #assign the other Amazon purchases to Amazon
         store_name = ifelse(str_detect(store_name,'AMZ')==TRUE,'AMAZON.COM',store_name))

Comment: You need to install either the `stringr` or `tidyverse` packages and load them with `library()` - sorry, I should have made that explicit.

Comment: I use other tidy packages.. just not the verse.. which is where I was a bit confused.. something in the tidyverse works perfect!  Thank you!